# Backstretch jQuery plugin doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, jquery-plugins, jquery-backstretch

I'd like to use the Backstretch jQuery plugin to create a fullscreen background picture on the starting page. Therefore I used the following code:

```
<div class="startslide">
<script>
$.backstretch('IMG_3628.jpg');
</script>
</div>




<footer class="footer">>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-backstretch/2.0.3/jquery.backstretch.min.js"></script>

</footer>
```

I don't really know what I did wrong as I did it the same way it is described in the demo....

I'd very much appreciate your help :)

Comment: Do you use it JUST for body background image? Because, you can always use CSS for it: http://jsfiddle.net/z0bzogxv/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-backstretch/2.0.3/jquery.backstretch.min.js"></script>




<div class="startslide">
    <script>
        $.backstretch(['IMG_3628.jpg']);
    </script>
</div>
```

Comment: First mistake is all about javascript hierarchy.

Comment: Cool it works now! Thanks a lot :) But why does everyone recommend to add script src's at the end of the page when you want to use it before?

Comment: everyone recommend to add script src's at the end of the page because of dom rendering issues. It is the best practise for rendering your html before js loaded. I just wanted to work your code clearly on the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to call jQuery plugin before calling those of Backtrech.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-backstretch/2.0.3/jquery.backstretch.min.js"></script>
```

Then, you have forget the `[]`. Try that :

```
$.backstretch(['IMG_3628.jpg']);
```

Please find this [**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/zlen/2j9k5jto/)